# Android - How to detect if night mode is on when using AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO

Tags: android, android-night-mode

I'm using Androids built in day/night mode functionality and I'd like to add an option to my app for `AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO`

I'm having a problem though because my app requires certain things to be colored programmatically, and I can't figure out how to check if the app considers itself in night or day mode.  Without that, I can't set a flag to choose the right colors.

Calling `AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode()` just returns AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO which is useless.

I don't see anything else that would tell me, but there must be something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get AppCompatDelegate current mode if default is auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391404/how-to-get-appcompatdelegate-current-mode-if-default-is-auto)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

```
int nightModeFlags =
    getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode &
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (nightModeFlags) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
         doStuff();
         break;

    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
         doStuff();
         break;

    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED:
         doStuff();
         break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I started going down the route of checking a colors string value to see which resource file it was coming from, but this is way better!

Comment: Please cite your sources. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391404/how-to-get-appcompatdelegate-current-mode-if-default-is-auto

Comment: @StarWind0 I did not find any other answers; this answer was derived purely from the API documentation.

Comment: @ephemient So? "Please cite your sources" share the link to the API documentation...

Answer (score 56):

If you are kotlin developer then you can use below code to judge dark mode.

```
when (context.resources?.configuration?.uiMode?.and(Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)) {
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {}
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {}
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> {}
}
```

For more about dark theme mode

> https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/DarkTheme

Comment: your when isn't exhaustive, and else would be better for the underfined case

Comment: Good solution, exactly what i needed

Comment: Hi, now we don't need to translate every question's answer in Kotlin as IDE automatically does the conversion. Anyway thanks for the effort although sadly it only contributes unnecessary scroll :(

Answer (score 19):

A very simple solution is to add a string resource like this.

**res/values/strings.xml**

```
<string name="mode">Day</string>
```

**res/values-night/strings.xml**

```
<string name="mode">Night</string>
```

And then wherever you need to check it:

```
if (resources.getString(R.string.mode) == "Day") {
    // Do Day stuff here
} else {
    // Do night stuff here
}
```

But you CAN NOT call this before `super.onCreate()` in an activity's life-cycle. It will always return "Day" before `onCreate`.

Comment: Does this require the theme to be a `DayNight` variant?

Comment: No, I don't think that should be a requirement

Answer (score 18):

to check for night mode you can do as below:

```
public boolean isNightMode(Context context) {
    int nightModeFlags = context.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    return nightModeFlags == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The bitwise operator in Java (which is used in @ephemient 's answer) is different 
in kotlin so the code might not be easily convertible for beginners. Here is the kotlin version just in case someone needs it:

```
    private fun isUsingNightModeResources(): Boolean {
        return when (resources.configuration.uiMode and 
Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> true
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> false
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> false
            else -> false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin Version :->

```
fun isDarkMode(context: Context): Boolean {
    val darkModeFlag = context.resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
    return darkModeFlag == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just a property that will actually tell you if you have Dark Mode ?

```
val Context.isDarkMode
    get() = if (getDefaultNightMode() == MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
        resources.configuration.uiMode and UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
    else getDefaultNightMode() == MODE_NIGHT_YES
```

Answer (score 3):

From Android Version R (30) there is provided a value in context.resources.configuration.isNightModeActive.

So you don't need to mask anymore.

Example in onConfigurationChanged:

```
private var _isNightModeActive: Boolean = false

override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        _isNightModeActive =
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                _resources.configuration.isNightModeActive
            } else {
                newConfig.uiMode and
                        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK ==
                        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin.Android

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Froyo)
{
    var uiModeFlags = Application.Context.Resources.Configuration.UiMode & UiMode.NightMask;
    switch (uiModeFlags)
    {
        case UiMode.NightYes:
            // dark mode
            break;
        case UiMode.NightNo:
            // default mode
            break;
        default:
            // default mode
            break;
    }
}
else
{
// default mode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with my UI tests, when try to get current theme in every answer code. It every time return the same value.

So I create static variable in **application class** and get theme for UI tests throw it:

```
@Theme
fun Context.getAppTheme(): Int? {
    val theme = when (resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> Theme.LIGHT
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> Theme.DARK
        else -> null
    }

    Application.theme = theme

    return theme
}
```

In Application class:

```
companion object {
    @Theme
    @RunNone var theme: Int? = null
}
```

May be it will be usefull for someone!

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using the flag **`resources.configuration.isNightModeActive`** is same as @Carsten. I would suggest a simple code structure.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R &&
        resources.configuration.isNightModeActive) {

    // code for night mode

} else {

    // code for day mode (or less than API-30)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found nothing of this to be working after changing the the app to dark theme with

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

Is there any way to know the system setting after changing the app with this method?
Thanks,
FF

Comment: I have the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896942/cant-detect-if-dark-theme-is-active-or-not-after-changing-it-with-appcompatdeleg/66913308#66913308) for anyone with the same "issue".