# Read Samsung's and other OEM dark/night mode system setting

Tags: android, kotlin, samsung-mobile

I'm inheriting the "Theme.AppCompat.DayNight" theme to support dark mode automatically on Android Q and manually on previous versions. On Settings I let the user choose either On, Off or Automatic and then I use this code:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(settings.darkMode())
```

Where *settings.darkMode* is:

```
        val darkValue =
            sharedPreferences.getString("PREF_DARK_THEME", null)
        return when (darkValue) {
            "ON" -> MODE_NIGHT_YES
            "OFF" -> MODE_NIGHT_NO
            else -> if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
            } else {
                MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY
            }
        }
```

However I'd like to add support for Samsung One UI's "**Night mode**". Is it possible to read that system setting? I'd like to do something like this:

```
            ...
            else -> if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
            } else if("samsung"==Build.MANUFACTURER && isSamsungNightModeEnabled()) {
                MODE_NIGHT_YES
            } else ...[add other brands]...
            } else {
                MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY
            }
```

Comment: Checking night mode flag in configuration works fine, I've tested it on S8. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170028/android-how-to-detect-if-night-mode-is-on-when-using-appcompatdelegate-mode-ni/44170179#44170179

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I was under the impression context.resources.configuration.uiMode read only the local configuration (i.e. what was set with AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode) but fortunately it seems I was wrong. It seems to be doing what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Pawel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59974987/read-samsungs-and-other-oem-dark-night-mode-system-setting#comment106066330_59974987) here's what I've done. It seems to be working fine.

```
    fun darkMode(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, context: Context): Int {
        val darkValue =
            sharedPreferences.getString("PREF_DARK_THEME", null)
        return when (darkValue) {
            "ON" -> MODE_NIGHT_YES
            "OFF" -> MODE_NIGHT_NO
            else -> if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
            } else {
                val nightModeFlags =
                    context.resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
                when (nightModeFlags) {
                    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> MODE_NIGHT_YES
                    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> MODE_NIGHT_NO
                    else -> MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I call `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(darkMode(preferences, this))` from the activity's onResume() method and the application changes its theme automatically after modifying the device's "Night mode" on the notification panel. Tested on a Note 9.