# How to get dark mode status on NativeScript 7

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

How to get dark mode status (dark / light mode on) on NativeScript 7?

Is there any way to get it using `@nativescript/core` as old way of `@nativescript/theme` doesn't seem to be working right now (probably isn't yet fully compatible with NativeScript 7.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean

> How to get dark mode status

`Theme.getMode()` will tell you if it is Auto, Dark or Light mode.
for example if i have enabled dark mode from my phone `Theme.getMode()` will return `auto` and not `Dark`

You can set modes

```
Theme.toggleMode();
```

or

```
Theme.setMode(Theme.Dark);
```

After this `Theme.getMode()` will return  `ns-dark` or `ns-light`

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

This is android specific, and works on Nativescript 8 (but should work on 7 too as it uses native android objects)

```
  import { Utils } from '@nativescript/core'
  const context = Utils.android.getApplicationContext();
  const flag = context.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & android.content.res.Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
  const isDarkMode = (flag === android.content.res.Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

Reference (android) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69052759/7450160