# How to detect phone system is dark theme or light theme?

Tags: java, android

Here is the code for the detect dark/light theme when we using the application.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    int mSysThemeConfig = newConfig.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    layout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    switch (mSysThemeConfig) {
        //Light theme
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lightTheme);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            break;
        //Dark theme
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.darkMode);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            break;
    }
}
```

How do I detect the dark/light theme when we start an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it

Maybe this can help you

```
int nightModeFlags =
getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode &
Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (nightModeFlags) {
case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
     doStuff();
     break;

case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
     doStuff();
     break;

case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED:
     doStuff();
     break;
}
```

OR you can go in this link

[Android - How to detect if night mode is on when using AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170028/android-how-to-detect-if-night-mode-is-on-when-using-appcompatdelegate-mode-ni)

Comment: thank you it is exactly what I want! Also, please remember to bind the view if you would like to change the attribute of the layout  `layout = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);` .  If cannot resolve method`getContext()`, change it to youractivity.this.get.....