# How to make your notification drop down as dark theme?

Tags: android

I had tried

1. Settings -> Display
2. Developer options -> Set Night mode

---

[image]

[image]

---

Still, I can hardly make the Android device have dark theme in drop down notification.

[image]

---

The reason I wanna to have dark color in drop down notification, because I'm currently debugging on this problem - [How to get the notification drop-down background color, and decide best text color when night Mode is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507712/how-to-get-the-notification-drop-down-background-color-and-decide-best-text-col)

Any idea? I am using Android Pie 9 emulator.

Comment: It's unclear what you are referring to as "drop down notification". Please use technical terms or be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via ADB on Android Q (Beta) emulator. Same command will work on Android P also but I think it doesn't has dark theme for notifications.

Enable Night Mode:

`adb shell settings put secure ui_night_mode 2`

Reboot to apply changes:

`adb reboot`

Disable Night mode:

`adb shell settings put secure ui_night_mode 1`